# Determine exponential time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've gotten pretty good at figuring out time complexity, but am still confused about how to determine exponential time algorithms. The algorithm below has a worst case running time O(k^n). How did they get this value? The first for-loop takes *n* time, the second for-loop takes *k* time, and the third for-loop with *q* is confusing. If the running time is *n* * *k* * *q*-something, how did they get O(k^n)?

```
int exp(k, n) {
    power = 1
    for i = 1 to n {
        newpower = 0
        for j = 1 to k {
            for q = 1 to power {
                newpower++
            }  
        }
        power = newpower
    }
    return (power)
}
```

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions like this again.